# PostgreSQL Many to many ratio and the total number of other Many

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, many-to-many

I have three tables **peoples**, **travels** and **hotel_books**.

```
CREATE TABLE peoples (
pe_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE travels (
tr_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
owner_id varchar,
town varchar
);

CREATE TABLE hotel_books (
hb_id varchar PRIMARY KEY,
pe_id varchar,
tr_id varchar,
hotel varchar
);

insert into peoples values('pe1', 'Nike');
insert into peoples values('pe2', 'Mike');
insert into peoples values('pe3', 'Dike');
insert into peoples values('pe4', 'Zike');
insert into peoples values('pe5', 'Pike');

insert into travels values('tr1', 'pe1', 'Paris');
insert into travels values('tr2', 'pe2', 'Bern');
insert into travels values('tr3', 'pe3', 'Madrid');
insert into travels values('tr4', 'pe4', 'NY');
insert into travels values('tr5', 'pe5', 'LA');
insert into travels values('tr6', 'pe1', 'London');
insert into travels values('tr7', 'pe1', 'Berlin');
insert into travels values('tr8', 'pe2', 'Rio');
insert into travels values('tr9', 'pe2', 'Washington');
insert into travels values('tr10', 'pe3', 'Kalkuta');
insert into travels values('tr11', 'pe3', 'Medina');
insert into travels values('tr12', 'pe4', 'Zagreb');
insert into travels values('tr13', 'pe4', 'Turin');
insert into travels values('tr14', 'pe1', 'Olimp');

insert into hotel_books values('hb1', 'pe1', 'tr1', 'Kimel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb2', 'pe2', 'tr2', 'Tynel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb3', 'pe3', 'tr3', 'Perel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb4', 'pe4', 'tr4', 'Turel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb5', 'pe5', 'tr5', 'Mawel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb6', 'pe5', 'tr6', 'Omel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb7', 'pe5', 'tr7', 'Gamel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb8', 'pe4', 'tr8', 'Remel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb9', 'pe4', 'tr9', 'Vemel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb10', 'pe5', 'tr1', 'Qarel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb11', 'pe4', 'tr2', 'Jawel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb12', 'pe4', 'tr3', 'Xamel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb13', 'pe3', 'tr4', 'Zemel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb14', 'pe5', 'tr4', 'Femel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb15', 'pe5', 'tr4', 'Remel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb16', 'pe4', 'tr4', 'Hemel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb17', 'pe4', 'tr4', 'Jemel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb18', 'pe5', 'tr4', 'Pemel');
insert into hotel_books values('hb19', 'pe5', 'tr4', 'Lemel');
```

How to make a query that will display all **travels** and the total number of **hotel_books** of a person. But the total number of **hotel_books** of a person should not take into account the records that he set for himself.

```
select
  travels.tr_id,
  count(hotel_books.pe_id <> travels.owner_id) as p_coun
from travels
LEFT OUTER JOIN peoples on travels.owner_id = peoples.pe_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN hotel_books on travels.tr_id = hotel_books.tr_id
group by travels.tr_id;
```

The result of my query does not display the real total number of **hotel_books** of a person:

```
     now result              expected result
|    | tr_id| p_coun |    |    | tr_id| p_coun |
----------------------    ----------------------
| 1  | tr10 |   0    |    | 1  | tr10 |   1    | 
| 2  | tr7  |   1    |    | 2  | tr7  |   2    |
| 3  | tr13 |   0    |    | 3  | tr13 |   5    |
| 4  | tr8  |   1    |    | 4  | tr8  |   3    |
| 5  | tr2  |   2    |    | 5  | tr2  |   3    |
| 6  | tr14 |   0    |    | 6  | tr14 |   2    |
| 7  | tr6  |   1    |    | 7  | tr6  |   2    |
| 8  | tr4  |   8    |    | 8  | tr4  |   5    |
| 9  | tr11 |   0    |    | 9  | tr11 |   1    |
| 10 | tr3  |   2    |    | 10 | tr3  |   1    |
| 11 | tr9  |   1    |    | 11 | tr9  |   3    |
| 12 | tr5  |   1    |    | 12 | tr5  |   0    |
| 13 | tr1  |   2    |    | 13 | tr1  |   2    |
| 14 | tr12 |   0    |    | 14 | tr12 |   5    |
----------------------    ----------------------
```

Work example: https://rextester.com/LTMNB15242

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question and add the desired result?

Comment: I added the expected result. @stickybit Look at this please.